# For statement over DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am looking for something similar for this:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       dataGridView1.Rows[index]....
    }
```

This is what i have try:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

        }
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: please be more specific and try to modify your question, we can't understand in what is your main problem here.